# ARKit Tracking - offsetting phone movement

Tags: ios, arkit

Currently I am trying to record the movements and rotations of my `SCNNode`. I am recording the movement data to a csv and then examining it afterwards. Everything is working fine except for the fact that when you move the phone, the data changes because of the `SCNNode` changing in world space. To elaborate, the node isn't moving or rotating but the movement of the phone is messing with the data in a way that makes it looks like it's moving.

I have read Apple's documentation about `ARSessionConfiguration.worldAlignment` and I think it could be possible to cancel out the movement of the phone using the `gravity` property of the node (default `worldAlignment`).

Does anyone have any advice as to how I could achieve this?

Update:

As mentioned above my original approach to solving this was to change the `ARSessionConfiguration`. When you change that, the only thing that really changes is where the `SCNNode` starts in the world space. Therefore, the change did not effect how the movement is represented.